# How to make multiple functions in foreach with id?

Tags: php

When i use function in foreach sure the results become: previously declared.

I use this code:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $seusag = $post['uagent'];
    function getNEOS() {
        global $seusag;
    } 
}
```

I thought about something like naming function with id & string, for example:

```
$nepoid = $post['id'];
function $nepoid() { }
```

But the results become error.

So, How to make one function in foreach that includes every post_id?

Explanation: if the function was outside foreach and for example contains "windows" only in array and the user posted a status his OS will be "windows" only, But if i have updated the function to be windows 10 and windows 7 his post won't get updated because the function's data has been already inserted into DB. But if the function was inside foreach then i can update user OS anytime depending on his user agent which is already inserted into DB during posting without need to edit his previous post from DB.

Comment: Can you please show us your code and explain properly what you're actually trying to do and, specifically, why you need it?

Comment: Why don't you just create one function outside the loop, which you call from within the loop?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Because I don't think this would work to do what you want.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson If i want to do what you have said i wouldn't ask that question!

Comment: And what you're trying to do makes no sense at all. Without knowing _why_ you need this (which we've asked) and what problem you're trying to solve, it's _impossible_ for us to come with any proper suggestions.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson If i have a function outside the loop and user posted a status today his post will contain his user os if his user os is defined in function, But if i have updated the function his user os won't get updated because the function outside the loop, that's why I want to use function in foreach with defined name/id for each post.

Comment: @I_I I don't think they'll use different values of `$seusag`.

Comment: Honestly, that explanation didn't really clear much up. You do know that you can pass arguments to functions instead of hard coding values or using `global` in them?

Comment: More explation: if the function outside the loop and contains "windows" only in array and the user posted a status his OS will be  windows, But if i have updated the function to windows 10 and windows 7 his post won't get updated because the data are already inserted into DB. But if the function was inside the loop then i can update user os anytime depending on their user agent without need to edit his previous post

Comment: Please edit your question with a proper explanation instead of spreading it out in comments.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Done

Comment: I still don't get all that: how do you want to "update" a function? Why not pass everything that might change as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this would achieve what you want to *happen*, but you can create multiple functions in a loop by using anonymous functions:

```
$functions = [];
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $seusag = $post['uagent'];
    $functions[$post] = function () use ($seusag) {
        return $seusag;
    }
}
```

I don't know whether `$seusag` inside the function will remain the same, though; I don't think it will.